# Google Cloud Messaging with Xcode 7 and iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I've managed to use GCM with Android devices, but now I'm trying to implement on an iOS app.

I think I followed all the necessary steps to be able to use the GCM service. I've followed the https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?configured=true to add the service to an existing app.

I think that everything is configured correct but I'm not able to receive any notification. I have the APN certificates and the GoogleService-info.plist file, on the console this is the output:

> 2016-01-05 13:47:53.864: GCM | Invalid key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion 
>   Connected to GCM
>   2016-01-05 13:47:57.501: GGLInstanceID | Invalid last checkin timestamp in future.
>   2016-01-05 13:47:57.501 TerneraGallega[1014:444977] Checkin successful with authId: 4958686017822257121, digest: KSJNg+Aj82uavBXrFeOAfA==, lastCheckinTimestamp: 1451998077000
>   Registration Token: nC-dd9fCvFs:APA91bHMfbvLczxSPLQsLeEJASU_RfV4wvVuPs2u4VJDtpC8oB2cm1AKr6cH_LFeLsQzb94Kk9iwez8fsOvgzNns_9DU3i8Ema1oCKIwcNFzenNpAhViyGHah4E7-RkQlg1durYSEQRD
>   Already subscribed to /topics/global

As soon as I receive this if I made a POST request with:

> {
>     "to" : "nC-dd9fCvFs:APA91bHMfbvLczxSPLQsLeEJASU_RfV4wvVuPs2u4VJDtpC8oB2cm1AKr6cH_LFeLsQzb94Kk9iwez8fsOvgzNns_9DU3i8Ema1oCKIwcNFzenNpAhViyGHah4E7-RkQlg1durYSEQRD",
>     "content_available" : true,
>     "notification" : {
>       "body" : "great match!",
>       "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
>       }
>   }

The first attempt it returns a success message but no log nor notification is shown in the device (with the application on the foreground)

After a few minutes, on another try of the POST request now it returns a failure with

> {
>     "multicast_id": 7256343774952522277,
>     "success": 0,
>     "failure": 1,
>     "canonical_ids": 0,
>     "results": [
>       {
>         "error": "NotRegistered"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

Now, I downloaded the GCM Example from the Google page, configured the APN and also got the GoogleService-info.plist, when launching the GCM Example Swift file as soon as it opens on the device it says:

> Registration Succesful! Check the xcode debug console fot the registration token that you can use...

After this, if you set a POST Request with

> {
>     "to" : "mVEtHyTXEOg:APA91bGvK_Uf2ZKgpguWUOto3CXQzIT1z22uJ446mYkNqMwL9VLDYdGtdm_4vS8rcl3T9OeqEC1UWbdKAOyuoweW1GiU0mv0cDSPW03y4XGx19JcR6rxsiWRNUjtADX6iNAW8wM8UBJl",
>     "content_available" : true,
>     "notification" : {
>       "body" : "great match!",
>       "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
>       }
>   }

it again returns a

> {
>     "multicast_id": 7435981433811133310,
>     "success": 0,
>     "failure": 1,
>     "canonical_ids": 0,
>     "results": [
>       {
>         "error": "NotRegistered"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

Can someone who has implemented GCM on an app could point me what I'm missing?

**-------EDIT-------**

Finally I've made it work by using a distribution certificate instead of a development certificate... it seems that I have all good configured but I'm missing something with the development certificate.

PS: In the APN Profile page under ID I have enabled both Push notification certificates (that's why I thought that everything was good configured)

But I'll leave this question open because I'm unable to use this under development circumstances

Comment: You can check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#response) for the possible causes of the `NotRegistered` error. It says: "If it is `NotRegistered`, you should remove the registration ID from your server database because the application was uninstalled from the device, or the client app isn't configured to receive messages."

Comment: Hi @gerardnimo, yes, that error means that you have to remove the token because the app no longer exist for that user (that certain not true) but I don't save the token yet, I want to have the system running first.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do effectively the same thing as the fix in your edit without messing with the certificates. Obviously this won't work if you already have everything setup, and are using both the development and production environments, but if you're just in the development stage it's easy enough to change.

In the Gcm example project (for objective-c) in application: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken I simply changed the code from:

```
    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
```

To

```
    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
```

I understand this isn't exactly a real fix, but it at least made it work without changing any certificates (as long as the production certificate is setup.

Comment: Hi @jrobe yes, in fact in swift 2 if you want to property use the production certificate with GCM you have to set the `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption = false` if not you'll always get the `{NotRegistered}`but when I was trying the development certificate I set the flag to true (but still did not work)