# How to remove GCM & SSL Errors

Tags: ios, ssl, google-cloud-messaging, cfnetwork

I integrated GCM into my app here is the code :

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import FBSDKLoginKit

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var connectedToGCM = false
var gcmSenderID: String?
var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)

    if(launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil){
        LocationService.sharedInstance.startMonitoringLocation()
    }

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
    let registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
        kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}



func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
    connectedToGCM = false
    LocationService.sharedInstance.restartMonitoringLocation()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({(error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.connectedToGCM = true
            print("Connected to GCM")
        }
    })

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    LocationService.sharedInstance.startUpdatingLocationTerminate()
}

func onTokenRefresh() {
    // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
    print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}

func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
    if (registrationToken != nil) {
        Gideon.notifId = registrationToken
        print("GCM token: \(registrationToken)")
    } else {
        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

And here is my log :

> 2016-04-25 22:57:41.805 TestApp[2044:]  App measurement
>   v.2003000 started 2016-04-25 22:57:41.805 TestApp[2044:]  To
>   enable debug logging set the following application argument:
>   -GMRDebugEnabled 2016-04-25 22:57:41.848: GCM | GCM library version 1.1.4 2016-04-25 22:57:41.868: GCM | Invalid
>   key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion GCM token:
>   k6uFlJWBSEg:APA91bGASVNpk-TwgturFp8BSVccFmPKtVLIg7MS6tcWNp4nvB26o3zdFVLUq6oqE1DtJOFAISiS6dZFu_Tt_p5c4v1WiQg7kZcq0hNIZKeabhx0Mg-2uzkJIkg-pvmpcvOHSBmtXYVg
>   2016-04-25 22:57:42.331 TestApp[2044:]  App measurement
>   enabled 2016-04-25 22:58:44.642 TestApp[2044:414848] CFNetwork
>   SSLHandshake failed (-9806) 2016-04-25 22:59:13.425
>   TestApp[2044:414848] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) 2016-04-25
>   22:59:34.918 Gideon[2044:414848] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
>   Connected to GCM 2016-04-25 23:09:54.593 TestApp[2044:414848] CFNetwork
>   SSLHandshake failed (-9806) 2016-04-25 23:10:08.681
>   TestApp[2044:414848] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) 2016-04-25
>   23:10:27.482 TestApp[2044:414848] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
>   Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.google.gcm error 2001.)

How can i fix those errors :

> GCM | Invalid key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion
>
> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
>
> Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.google.gcm error 2001.)

Thank's in advance

Comment: Is this related to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612467/google-cloud-messaging-with-xcode-7-and-ios-9

Comment: No, my notifications are working perfect i just want to remove those warnings